# Compare two list object but some of the object param is nul

Tags: java, android

before ask i saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437771/compare-two-list-objects) too. but i didn't get that.

I have two lists.

```
List<Contact> serverContacts
```

`serverContacts` have 4 item
and

```
List<Contact> phoneContact
```

have 20 item.

**and my Contact model is**

```
private String firstName;
private String id;
private String lastName;
private LinkedUser linkedUser;
private String cellphoneNumber;
private String email;
private String uniqueId;
private long notSeenDuration;
private boolean hasUser;
```

**This is the method for doing compare**

```
List<Contact> serverContacts = adapter.fromJson(chatMessage.getContent());
if (serverContacts != null) {
    List<Contact> phoneContact = getPhoneContact(getContext());
    for (int i = 0; i < phoneContact.size(); i++) {
        if (serverContacts.size() > i) {
            if(phoneContact.get(i).getCellphoneNumber().equals(serverContacts.get(i).getCellphoneNumber())) {
                System.out.println("Match Found " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `phone contact` list just fill two param of the `Contact` model, `cellphoneNumber` and `firstName`.
Becuase the two object of these two lists are not exactly the same, I mean just one of them in these two have the same `cellphoneNumber`. Then I tried to compare these two based on `cellphoneNumber`.

> I think this might work when both of them have the same size.!!

Comment: you are checking exact same position for both array list which might not same.. i would suggest to iterate one over other to get result

Comment: @Mohit do you think it is fast?

Comment: yes it is and also the correct way.. by this you will compare each item of one to every item or other which cant fail you easily

Comment: Ans this type of approach is used in sorting so it is easy and fast too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this:

```
    List<Contact> serverContacts = adapter.fromJson(chatMessage.getContent());
    if (serverContacts != null) {
        List<Contact> phoneContact = getPhoneContact(getContext());
        for (int i = 0; i < serverContacts.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < phoneContact.size(); j++) {
                if(serverContacts.get(i).getCellphoneNumber().equals(phoneContact.get(j).getCellphoneNumber())) {
                    System.out.println("Match Found " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this solution does not scale, it can quickly be a performance bottleneck. Better use HashSet and contains.

Comment: @BluEOS in this case two lists only have 4 and 20 elements therefore i think this way is quicker and easier to achieve his goal.

Comment: why not, but use for(Contact c1 : serverContacts) and for(Contact c2 : phoneContacts) in order to not call size() every loop step... From what I understand, the code is running on Android devices, and we all know how slow they are.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend a 2 steps solution.

1. - fill a HashSet with your server contacts
   - fill a HashSet with your phone contacts
2. - iterate the phone HashSet and check (with the contains method) if the phone number is in the server contacts HashSet.